# What does "attain values" mean for an analytic function here?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Here's a question in complex analysis that I don't get, neither do I understand the first part of its answer given in the book. I would really appreciate some help.

**Question:**

> Show that if $f(z)$ is an entire function, and there is a nonempty disk
> such that $f(z)$ does not attain any values in the disk, then $f(z)$ is
> constant.

**Answer:**

> If $f$ does not attain values in the disk $|w - c| < \epsilon$, then
> $1/(f - c)$ is bounded, hence constant by Liouville's theorem, and $f$
> is constant.

**Entire function:** a function that is analytic on the entire complex plane.
**Liouville's theorem:** every bounded entire function is a constant.

Source of the question: Gamelin, Complex Analysis.

Happy New Year!

Comment: "$f$ attains the value $v$" means $v$ is in the image of $f$, that is, $v=f(z)$ for some $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for some disc $B(a,r)$ we have that

$$ f(\mathbb{C}) \cap B(a,r) = \emptyset$$

Then, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$,

$$ | f(z) - a | \geq r$$

and you can consider its multiplicative inverse and apply Liouville.